# Timers and browsers - unfocused or minimized window

Tags: javascript, browser

I have a javascript Timer that perform an AJAX request, I need to know if there is any browser/os combination that stops executing timers when the user minimizes or unfocus the browser window.

Anyone seen a comprehensible test case about this around the web?

Comment: there is `window.onblur` and `window.onfocus` where you can clear the timers and then in onfocus restart them.

Comment: @PatrickEvans not exactly what I need. I can't have my browser stoping executing the ajax request even if the user minimizes the window. If that is not possible in some browser/os I need to do some manual treatment for that case.

Comment: then there is no problem setInterval/setTimeout does not stop just because window does not have focus as far as i know, i have never personally seen it stop without having actually stopped it with the clear* functions.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use what Patrick said `window.onblur` and `clearInterval`. Example of clearInterval: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_setinterval3